# Firefox users: Is it redundant to have AdBlock and Flashblock installed alongside noscript?

Tags: firefox, adblock, noscript

I have them all running and FF seems to be working fine (for about a month now). Apologies in advance if this is a dumb question.

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AdBlock Plus blocks both iFrame ads and JS ads, but NoScript only blocks JS in general. FlashBlock is unnecessary, as NoScript, for a long time, blocked plugins such as Flash and Java as well as JS.

You can also configure NoScript to block Flash for trusted sites as well in the Options.

Comment: While flashblock might be unnecessary for blocking ads, but it is still useful for other things, like http://stackoverflow.com/q/3470664/23118.

Answer (score 1):

I do not use any of these, but since most ads are run by JS, then noscript should block them anyways. But some ads can be rendered via PHP, then it would not block it.

I am not sure how any of these programs work internally, so I cant be of much help. But if you absolutely have JS and ads and flash, then I don't see why you cant be extra careful :).

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. The case where you will notice a different is when you need JS for a page to work, but you don't want your eyes burned by a Flash ad being driven by that JS.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Noscript protects against click hijacking and javascript.  It doesn't protect against Flash ads or any other type of image/java based ads.

Adblock prevents ads from loading which may not be javascript based or those in youtube videos, images, flash, etc. in the selective fashion which Adblock can.  While Noscript can prevent flash from running it blocks all flash rather than just ads (same with java blocking).

Comment: Since when does Adblock Plus somehow read into the ActionScript of Flash movies (such as the ones YouTube uses to present its videos) to parse out ads?

Comment: noscript can block flash as well.

Comment: Whoops, bad typing there. editing it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that using Adblock and Flashblock together significant slows my Firefox down and makes it feel sluggish.